# Visio - add connectors to Selector Switch

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm using Visio's Basic Electrical template, which includes a Selector Switch component. It's a 1-pole, 4-way switch.

Can I add a fifth connector, or is there another component I can use?

Incidentally, the diagram is for a Stratocaster guitar, and the actual switch is a 4 pole, 5-way.

Sorry, although I was able to upload an image, my reputation doesn't allow me to include one in this post. You might still find the screenshot I uploaded here:

[image: link to uploaded screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to add a 5th connector.
One way to do this would be to put the select switch on the page, open the group shape (don't ungroup it!), add a new circle shape in the appropriate place for your 5th terminal, add a new wire as well. Then close the shape. That job should take less than 2 minutes.
You won't be able to get the select rotor to move to that location though.